# How to draw multiple lines that snap to a grid using Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am building a simple line drawing tool using FabricJs and canvas. Using the mouse someone can draw a line that follows grid lines. **Like this picture:**

[image: Figure 1]

My goal is the restrict the line to be only drawn vertically, horizontally and diagonally following the grid. So far the lines don't stick to the grid, the lines can be draw freely on the canvas.

See picture with red lines:

[image: Wrong way]

I'm not sure how to implement that part, any help would be appreciated.

Here is what I have so far.
Thank you.

```js
var canvasA = new fabric.Canvas('a', { selection: false });

var grid = 30;

// create grid
//line
var line, isDown;


function createGrid(board) {
  for (var i = 0; i < (600 / grid); i++) {
    board.add(new fabric.Line([ i * grid, 0, i * grid, 600], { stroke: '#000', selectable: false }));
    board.add(new fabric.Line([ 0, i * grid, 600, i * grid], { stroke: '#000', selectable: false }))
  }
}
//create grids

createGrid(canvasA);


//handle line drawing
drawLine(canvasA);


function drawLine (board) {
// add objects
board.on('mouse:down', function(o){
  isDown = true;
  var pointer = board.getPointer(o.e);
  var points = [ pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y ];
  line = new fabric.Line(points, {
    strokeWidth: 2,
    fill: 'black',
    stroke: 'red',
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
  
  });
  board.add(line);
});

board.on('mouse:move', function(o){
  if (!isDown) return;
  var pointer = board.getPointer(o.e);
  line.set({ x2: pointer.x, y2: pointer.y });
  board.renderAll();
});

board.on('mouse:up', function(o){
  isDown = false;
});

}
```

```css
canvas{
    
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 3px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 240px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding-left: 0;

}


.boards  {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 0;
}

    .boards canvas {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: transparent;
        margin: 3px;
        width: 120px;
        height: 240px;
    
    }
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.js"></script>
        <h1>Fabric Js Snap To grid </h1>
        <div class="boards">
        <canvas id="a" width="120" height="240"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find vertical lines using this if statement.
`if(Math.abs(line.x1 - line.x2) > Math.abs(line.y1 - line.y2))`
And on mouse up remove
`board.remove(line);`

```js
var canvasA = new fabric.Canvas('a', { selection: false });

var grid = 30;

// create grid
//line
var line, isDown;


function createGrid(board) {
  for (var i = 0; i < (600 / grid); i++) {
    board.add(new fabric.Line([ i * grid, 0, i * grid, 600], { stroke: '#000', selectable: false }));
    board.add(new fabric.Line([ 0, i * grid, 600, i * grid], { stroke: '#000', selectable: false }))
  }
}
//create grids

createGrid(canvasA);


//handle line drawing
drawLine(canvasA);


function drawLine (board) {
// add objects
board.on('mouse:down', function(o){
  isDown = true;
  var pointer = board.getPointer(o.e);
  var points = [ pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y ];
  line = new fabric.Line(points, {
    strokeWidth: 2,
    fill: 'black',
    stroke: 'red',
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
  
  });
  board.add(line);
});

board.on('mouse:move', function(o){
  if (!isDown) return;
  var pointer = board.getPointer(o.e);
  line.set({ x2: pointer.x, y2: pointer.y });
  board.renderAll();
});

board.on('mouse:up', function(o){
   if(Math.abs(line.x1 - line.x2) > Math.abs(line.y1 - line.y2))
     board.remove(line);
  isDown = false;
});

}
```

```css
canvas{
    
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 3px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 240px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding-left: 0;

}


.boards  {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 0;
}

    .boards canvas {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: transparent;
        margin: 3px;
        width: 120px;
        height: 240px;
    
    }
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.js"></script>
        <h1>Fabric Js Snap To grid </h1>
        <div class="boards">
        <canvas id="a" width="120" height="240"></canvas>
```